# What re write rule is required to stop https on sub domain

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, subdomain

I have the following rewrite rule in my domains .htaccess to add https to my existing http domain. **Example www.mydomain.com**

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

The issue I am having is the https is also being applied to my sub domain.

**Example demos.mydomain.com**

What code is required in the .htaccess to prevent the https on my sub domain?

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: I created a .htaccess in the folder of the sub domain and added the code you provided.  Works perfect. Thanks for your help Abhishek